# Cannot query Active Directory using ServerBind on non-domain computer in Windows PE

Tags: security, active-directory, directoryservices, winpe

I have a need to write a .NET application which will query Active Directory while running in [Windows PE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766093%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) on a computer which is not yet a member of the domain.

We are running this during a Microsoft Deployment Toolkit task sequence (note that MDT 2012 has been configured to load support for .NET into the WinPE environment - the .NET application is starting without any problems).

I am using the code below to bind to the domain:

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(
  path,
  username,
  password,
  AuthenticationTypes.ServerBind | AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
```

I have tried a `path` both of the form:

`LDAP://domainServer/dc=domain,dc=name`

And also without a domain controller name as

`LDAP://dc=domain,dc=name`

I have also tried using a `username` both of the form `domain\username` and also just `username`.

The `DirectoryEntry` object seems to be constructed okay, but when I try to execute `Console.Writeline(entry.Name)` to confirm a valid connection has been made, I get the following exception:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80005000): Unknown
>   error (0x80005000)    at
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
>   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()    at
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_Name()

I have tried other variations on this code, trying to execute LDAP queries with various filters, trying to rewrite it in VBScript, etc... but the code posted above is the simplest example I could come up with which reproduces the problem.

From what I have read, in a scenario like this you would always need to use `AuthenticationTypes.ServerBind` and that is why I am trying to specify the code within the ADSI LDAP path. But what is wrong with the code above? To me, it looks like it is passing all needed information in the parameters to the `DirectoryEntry` constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to get it work, but it's not supported by Microsoft. This post helped me a lot. It works, tested and approved for a deployment of new computers :)

Get the `ADSIxXX.inf` from the zip file to `C:\ADSI`

Copy the following files from a Windows/System32 to `C:\ADSI`. Carefull of Architecture 
 `x86 x64` -

```
   adsldp.dll
   adsmsext.dll
   adsnt.dll
   mscoree.dll
   mscorier.dll
   mscories.dll
```

Mount the `bootimage.wim`

No need to load Package (Your WinPE is already configured to load .NET API), juste add ADSI driver:

```
Dism /Image:C:\Mount /Add-Driver /Driver:C:\ADSI\ADSIxXX.inf /forceunsigned
```

No need to load his script

Unmount the `bootimage.wim`

Then it's done, if your .NET application is well implement ;)
I'm not sur the PIPE | is supported as an argument too, just set to `AuthenticationTypes.Secure` -

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(
  path,
  username,
  password,
  AuthenticationTypes.ServerBind | AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
```

Link: http://www.deploymentresearch.com/Research/tabid/62/EntryId/74/ADSI-plugin-for-WinPE-4-0.aspx#AddComment